Hide child component from parent with transition
I created this modal component:
interface ModalProps extends PropsWithChildren {
  /***/
  onClose: () => void;
}

const Modal: FC<ModalProps> = ({
  /***/
  onClose,
  children
}) => {
  const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsVisible(true);
  }, []);

  function handleTransitionEnd() {
    if (!isVisible) {
      onClose();
    }
  }
  return (
    <div
      className={clsx(
        'fixed left-0 right-0 bottom-0 top-0 w-full z-[9999] bg-black/40 transition-opacity duration-300',
        isVisible ? 'opacity-100' : 'opacity-0'
      )}
      onClick={() => setIsVisible(false)}
      onTransitionEnd={handleTransitionEnd}
    >
      <div
        className={clsx(
          'bg-white absolute left-1/2 -translate-x-1/2 transition-transform duration-300 rounded-2xl overflow-auto',
          isVisible ? 'bottom-4 translate-y-0' : 'bottom-0 translate-y-full'
        )}
        onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>) =>
          event.stopPropagation()
        }
      >
      </div>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Modal;

And this is its parent component:
const Parent: FC = () => {
  const [isModalVisible, setIsModalVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setIsModalVisible(true)}>Open Modal</button>
      {isModalVisible && (
        <Modal onClose={() => setIsModalVisible(false)}>
          <div className="bg-white flex justify-center items-center">
            <button onClick={() => setIsModalVisible(false)}>
              Close Modal
            </button>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Parent;

I added some transition to modal when I open it the transition applies. when I click on X button modal or its backdrop it hides and also the transition applies. but when I click on Close Modal button that I passed to it as child, in other word when I manage modal's display from parent's state the transition does not work. how can I change modal component to fix it?
PS: I also tried to pass the isVisible to modal and then I used an useEffect on it but did not work
